# Zero Jaccard accuracy in u-net implementation with keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, image-segmentation

I am trying to use u-net with keras implementation, I am using the following repo
https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet
it works well, but my problem is a two-class segmentation problem, so I want to set the accuracy metric to jaccard, and also the loss function

I tried to define the function:

```
def Jac(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(K.round(y_pred))
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    num = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    den = K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) - num
    return num / den
```

and call it in the compilation:

```
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = ['binary_crossentropy'], metrics = [Jac])
```

When I do that the jaccard accuracy in every iteration decreases till it reach ZERO !!
Any explanation of why that happen ??
P.S: The same thing happens with the Dice.
P.S: The output layer is conv 1 * 1 with sigmoid activation function

## Update:

Attached the original implementation in keras of the binary accuracy:

```
def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)
```

And I can see that it also uses rounding to get the output prediction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're rounding your function (`K.round`).

That causes two problems:

- (real problem) The function is not differentiable and will not be capable of being a loss function (A "None values not supported" error will be shown)
- Whenever your network is unsure and has any values below 0.5, those values will be considered zero.

If the amount of black (zero) pixels in `y_true` is greater than the white (1) ones, this will happen:

- your network will tend to predict everything to zero first, and this will indeed result in a better binary crossentropy loss!

  - And also a better Jaccard if not rounded
  - But a zero Jaccard if rounded
- and only later, when the learning rates are more finely adjusted, it will start bringing out the white pixels where they should be.

You should really be using a non-rounded function for both reasons above.
And plot your outputs sometimes to see what is going on :)

Notice that if you're using this as a loss function, multiply it by -1 (because you will want it to decrease, not increase)

Comment: Thank you!, I know about the differentiation problem, but I use it as an accuracy metric, not a loss function,  
concerning rounding, I think I need to round in order to know the output prediction of the network as a TWO classes, if I left it unrounded (continuous) then how can I know the two classes, and consequently how canI measure the output accuracy as compared to the ground truth??

Comment: You only need to round the "output", and only "when you want" to know the classes. If you want a metric, don't round it, because you will want to see the evolution of the network. You can't see the evolution from a black image to the right image while the values are between 0 and 0.5.

Comment: hmmm, I don't get you, Jaccard itself (and also Dice) is designed to see how much two images are overlapped!, so we multiply them and count number of ones, so the two input images (ground truth and prediction) must be *binary*

Another thing: kindly check the update which I attached

Comment: There is no "binary" when using neural networks. They work "continuous", always. If you put your metric binary, you will "not see it evolve continously" (but your network is evolving continuously). You can use two metrics, one binary for "the real value you want" and nother one continuous, so you can see something is happening.

Comment: If you only use a binary metric, you will have to wait all the training until your network finally starts outputting values greater than 0.5, until then you will only see zeros, as explained in the answer.

Comment: That makes sense really! thank you! , but one last question is about the original accuracy metric in keras (I attached it in my question) it is using rounding, however it produces reasonable values

Comment: At the beginning, you have random results, values greater than 0.5 and values lower than 0.5. The rounding will produce ones and zeros, and the value will be some number. As the network tends to produce zero results, some pixels jump from 1 to 0, but not all of them at once.  The metric evolves while there are pixels crossing from >0.5 to <0.5. After that, it will stay a while with all pixels below the line, until they start crossing the line again, but now forming reasonable images.

Comment: I was training a few U-nets, and they were always doing this. First they put everything to zero, only later they start forming pictures. It was quite hard, actually, to make it produce results. Many times they got stuck in the zero values. Using "linear" or "tanh" activations made it easier than using "relu".

Comment: Yes I got it, Thank you very much your explanation is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try these functions bellow, copied from [github](https://github.com/ZFTurbo/ZF_UNET_224_Pretrained_Model/blob/master/zf_unet_224_model.py). Use jacard_coef in keras metrics and if you want jacard_coef_loss keras loss

```
def jacard_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (intersection + 1.0) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) - intersection + 1.0)


def jacard_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -jacard_coef(y_true, y_pred)

model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = [jacard_coef_loss], metrics = [jacard_coef])
```

Comment: I have seen these functions before and it is the same as mine except that he adds (1.0 for smoothing and to avoid devision by zero), and it also goes to zero

Comment: I have, and the problem remains, loss function should have no effect on changing the accuracy that appears, I am just changing the metric but all the training process is the same

Comment: yes, do you get the problem correctly? it starts with accuracy 0.1 for example, and decreases gradually till zero, which is not logical ! at the same time it works very well with the conventional binary accuracy